# How to download patent sequence listings?

Tags: search, patent-services

I'd like to download the associated sequence listing for a patent. However, I can't seem to find a convenient way. I am aware that Patentscope hast a [sequence listing browser](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/sequences.jsf). However, even though I know the patent's publication date, I can't seem to find it there.

Is there a database that makes the sequence listing available together with the actual patent?

PS: the patent I'm interested in in this specific case can be found [here](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2019212351&_cid=P11-LQGL72-20521-1)

Comment: I didn't find a separate sequence file either. That said, the cited document is only an application and not yet a patent. You can find the documents on the link you provided or else find the publication on Google Patents here: https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2019212351A2/en?oq=WO2019212351

Comment: In a listing of sequence files that application number is missing . Looks like they refer to it in the spec but didn’t actually file any sequences.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite thanks for that info. I wasn't aware that a patent can even be filed without also providing the sequences.

Comment: As @EricS pointed out it is an application not a patent.  Screwing up a filing is very possible.